# how to insert a <td> to a <tr> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a `table` with few rows, I just need to re arrange them, I am able to fetch `<td>` and `<tr>` and now what I need to do is to insert them back in a custom order

```
 $('.white-header').each(function() {  //white-header is the class used for <tr>
    var tr = $(this);

    var td1 = tr.find('td:eq(4)'); // indices are zero-based here
    var td2 = tr.find('td:eq(5)');
    var td3 = tr.find('td:eq(6)');
    var td4 = tr.find('td:eq(7)');
    var td5 = tr.find('td:eq(8)');
    var td6 = tr.find('td:eq(9)');
    var td7 = tr.find('td:eq(10)');
    td1.remove();
    td2.remove();
    td3.remove();
    td4.remove();
    td5.remove();
    td6.remove();
    td7.remove();
    tr.insert(td7); // here am getting errors, i tried .append also
    tr.insert(td6);
    tr.insert(td4);
});
```

i just need to know how to insert `td` to this `tr` (currently `tr` is blank i guess, after removing all `td`)

Comment: insert isn't a jQuery method. use [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ for various methods of manipulating the DOM.

Comment: append is also not working , is this some jquery version issue , or this is something cuz iam doing it :-(

Comment: @user3239473 with you last edit, you have removed all the formatting and code indentation if you'r unaware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `.remove()` at all. All you need is to use `append` and `prepend` (or `appendTo` and `prependTo`) in a clever way to rearrange your cells. These methods do not copy DOM nodes, they move them, so removal is completely unnecessary.

[Quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/dYaTM/):

```
$('.white-header').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this);  

    tr.find('td:eq(4)').appendTo(tr);
    tr.find('td:eq(6)').appendTo(tr);
    tr.find('td:eq(9)').prependTo(tr);
});
```

*(in my example the order of the elements might seem strange at the end, because I don't run `:eq` on the original order, but always on the already changed order - this is only a quick example)*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to *append* the **deleted** objects, You need to make clone of `<td>` and remove the `<td>` objects you have later append the cloned objects of insert

```
$('.white-header').each(function() {  //white-header is the class used for <tr>
    var tr = $(this);
    var td1 = tr.find('td:eq(4)'); // indices are zero-based here
    var td2 = tr.find('td:eq(5)');
    var td3 = tr.find('td:eq(6)');
    var td4 = tr.find('td:eq(7)');
    var td5 = tr.find('td:eq(8)');
    var td6 = tr.find('td:eq(9)');
    var td7 = tr.find('td:eq(10)');
    td1.remove();
    td2.remove();
    td3.remove();
    td4Cloned = td4.clone();
    td4.remove();
    td5.remove();
    td6Cloned = td6.clone();
    td6.remove();
    td7Cloned = td7.clone();
    td7.remove();

    tr.insert(td7Cloned); // here am getting errors, i tried .append also
    tr.insert(td6Cloned);
    tr.insert(td4Cloned);
});
```

Comment: `.remove()` does not destroy the DOM element, it simply detaches it from its parent!

Comment: Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM, http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: @UweB Then what's the use of `.detach()`.?

Comment: As pointed out in the documentation, detach will preserve any `.data()`, whereas `.remove()` will not.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I made a JSFiddle to illustrate what `.remove()` does: With remove (http://jsfiddle.net/KELMP/), the `.data('x')` gets destroyed, whereas detach (http://jsfiddle.net/KELMP/1/) preserves it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Me too, I didn't know about `.detach()` until you mentioned it, and wanted to find out the difference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.detach()`

```
$('.white-header').each(function() {  //white-header is the class used for <tr>
    var tr = $(this);    

    var td1 = tr.find('td:eq(4)').detach(); // indices are zero-based here
    var td2 = tr.find('td:eq(5)');
    var td3 = tr.find('td:eq(6)').detach();
    var td4 = tr.find('td:eq(7)').detach();
    var td5 = tr.find('td:eq(8)');
    var td6 = tr.find('td:eq(9)');
    var td7 = tr.find('td:eq(10)');
    td1.remove();
    td2.remove();
    td3.remove();
    td5.remove();

    tr.append(td7); // here am getting errors, i tried .append also
    tr.append(td6);
    tr.append(td4);    
});
```

Comment: You'r welcome, the code was not indented in original post so i suppose all the answers will have the issue (: